# Why a cover of a set exist?

Tags: measure-theory

In the definition of the measure, we have that $$m^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty |Q_i|\mid E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i\right\}$$
where $Q_j$ are closed cube. My question is : Why for any $E$ there exists closed cube s.t. $E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty  Q_i$ ? Same, by the definition of the infimum, if $E$ is a set and $\varepsilon>0$, there is a cover $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty Q_j\supset E$ s.t. $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j|<m^*(E)+\varepsilon,$$

but I don't know, the existence of those $Q_j$ looks strange to me. Why there are such cube ?

Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: What is a "closed cube" in a general topological space? The definition you give seems to be the outer measure on $\mathbb R^n$, but you're asking a question about how it functions on a topological space.

Comment: I re-edit my question @MiloBrandt

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what space you are in, so what you mean by a closed cube is unclear.

However, if you are in $\mathbb R^n$, then $Q_i=[-i,i]^n$ is a closed cube, and $\{Q_i\}$ covers all of $\mathbb R^n$, and hence any subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Nobody said the sum had to be finite. The range of values for $m^*(E)$ is $[0,+\infty]$ - that is, it can take the value $+\infty$.

Your rephrasing in terms of $\epsilon$ only makes sense when $m^*(E)$ is finite, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the outer and inner measure is to measure how far a set is from being measurable. This way, we can use the measure for more sets than just the $\sigma$-algebra.

Intuitively, the difference between the outer and inner measure of $M$ measures how big is the ("smallest") difference between measurable $E$ and $F$ where $F \subset M \subset E$.

Now the answer to your question is given in your question: Because $X$ is always such a cover.

Note that in your example, the only measurable sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$. For any other set, the outher measure is the the measure of $X$ and the inner measure is the measure of $\emptyset$. This is telling us that the measure cannot be extended in a "very simple" way to other sets. [now most of the times there are ways of extending this measure, but not in a "trivial" way.]